# Moving mod_rewrite rules from conf.d to .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am having an issue with getting mod_rewrite rules working in .htaccess after moving them from the conf.d folder.
I do understand for performance sake that it would be wiser to leave it sitting there but I have folder serving php on the document root which I do not want these same rules applied to.

And here it is..  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/(\d+)/? /index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\d+)/? /index.php?p=$1&s=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(manual|admin|awstats)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/? /index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Edited with additional config:

```
<Location "/admin/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings
    #PythonDebug Off
</Location>

Alias /adminmedia/ "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"

<Directory "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media">
    Options -Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, couldn't you wrap the rules you want for a specific folder in a `Directory` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as astated by @Jason McCreary you can put your rewriteRules in a `<Directory>` section. It will be limited to that directory only. The main advantage from a `Directory` versus a `.htaccess` is that you do not need to allow anything in `AllowOverride`. So that's:

- **safer**: no risk of anyone altering apache configuration by using a .htaccess (`use AllowOverride None`)
- **faster**: apache does not need to search for any .htaccess in your directory or in all the parents directories (us your `AllowOverride None` in a `<Directory />` section, start on top of the filesystem)

Now there are some difference on the rewrite Engine when used in `.htaccess` files, you may need to play with **rewriteBase** for example.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the directory is configured with `AllowOverride FileInfo` (this is required for using the RewriteEngine)

Comment: I am at complete loggerheads with this issue. The scenario is this: I have a django site at www.example.com setup with mod_python (this was the original setup and I haven't touched it at all) with all the configurations sitting in the conf.d folder.  Now I am trying to serve an additional PHP folder at www.example.com/(phpfolder)  The issue which I am seeing is that the rewrite rules for the main site are affecting the folder serving the PHP content hence I wanted to figure out a way to move the rewrite rules from the conf.d directory a .htaccess at the document root.